# Installing pip in Raspberry pi3

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-2.x

**Sorry I am newbie, when I try to install pip using following command**

```
$ wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
$ sudo python get-pip.py
```

**I get following error**

```
ERROR: This script does not work on Python 2.7 The minimum supported Python version is 3.6. Please use https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py instead.
```

**Please help me out**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you have two options, either use `python3` with

```
sudo apt install python3 -y
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python3 get-pip.py
```

Or install it with `python2`:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
```

But if you just want to install `pip` you can do it with:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip -y
```

or

```
sudo apt install python-pip -y
```

Comment: Thanks alot, it worked

Comment: @ShAn I am glad it worked. Please consider to mark it as solved. There is a mark button next to the answer.